# No Transfer Functionality on ERC721?

Tags: solidity, tokens, metamask, nft, goerli

I wrote a smart contract that mints an nft using the ERC721 _mint function. When the token is minted the "Send" functionality is grayed out in Metamask on the Goerli Chain. I don't understand where the problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is MetaMask and their current support to NFTs, see: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058961911-How-do-I-send-receive-or-cash-out-an-NFT-

> Sending an NFT (an ERC-721 token; transfers of ERC-1155, another token standard used for NFTs, is not yet supported) in MetaMask is very similar to sending conventional tokens (usually ERC-20 tokens, often just referred to as coins or crypto). Currently, this functionality should only be attempted in MetaMask Mobile.

So, apparently just open your phone and try over their :)